# Data is not getting displayed on GUI

Tags: node.js, user-interface, electron, serial-port, desktop-application

I have created a destop application using electron.js. In this application, I am reading continuous data from an obd tool, connected through UART via USB. When i run the application, data is getting displayed in the console/terminal but I am not able to display same data on GUI

This is my "main.js" code

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const { SerialPort } = require("serialport");
const path = require('path')

// Create a new Electron window
function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  // Load the HTML file for the GUI
  win.loadFile("index.html");
  return win;
}

// Wait until Electron is ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const mainWindow = createWindow();

  // Initialize serial port and data handling
  let receivedData = "";
  let temperature = [];
  let voltage = [];
  let packData = [];

  var port = "COM5";
  const serialPort = new SerialPort({
    path:port,
    baudRate: 9600
});

  serialPort.on("open", function () {
    console.log("-- Connection opened --");
  });

  serialPort.on("data", function (data) {
    const newData = data.toString(); // Convert incoming data to a string
    receivedData += newData; // Append new data to the accumulated data
    
    // For Temperature //
    if (newData.endsWith("*")) {
      const startIndexT = receivedData.indexOf("^") + 1;
      const endIndexT = receivedData.indexOf("C");
      if (startIndexT !== -1 && endIndexT !== -1 && startIndexT < endIndexT) {
        const temperatureValue = receivedData.substring(startIndexT, endIndexT);
        temperature.push(temperatureValue);
      }
  
      //For Voltage //
      const startIndexV = receivedData.indexOf("#") + 1;
      const endIndexV = receivedData.indexOf("*");
      if (startIndexV !== -1 && endIndexV !== -1 && startIndexV < endIndexV) {
        const voltageValue = receivedData.substring(startIndexV, endIndexV);
        voltage.push(voltageValue);
      }
      // For SOC, Pack Voltage and Pack Current
      const startTag = "VCS";
      const endTag = "VCS";
      const startIndexP = receivedData.indexOf(startTag) + startTag.length;
      const endIndexP = receivedData.lastIndexOf(endTag);
      if (startIndexP !== -1 && endIndexP !== -1 && startIndexP < endIndexP) {
        const packValues = receivedData.substring(startIndexP, endIndexP).split(",");
        if (packValues.length === 3) {
          const [soc, voltage, current] = packValues;
          packData.push({ 
            SOC: soc,
            Pack_Voltage: voltage,
            Pack_Current: current
          });
        }
      }
  
      // console.log("Complete Data received: " + receivedData);
      mainWindow.webContents.send("received-data", receivedData);
      console.log("Temperature values: " + temperature.join(", "));
      console.log("Voltage values: " + voltage.join(", "));
      console.log(packData);



      mainWindow.webContents.send("temperature-d", temperature);
      mainWindow.webContents.send("voltage-d", voltage);
      mainWindow.webContents.send("pack-data", packData);
  
      receivedData = ""; // Clear the accumulated data for the next round
      temperature = []; // Clear the temperature values for the next round
      voltage =[]; // Clear the voltage values for the next round
      packData = []; // Clear the pack data for the next round 
    }
  });
});

// Quit when all windows are closed
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// Activate the Electron app
app.on("activate", () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

This is my "index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Data Display</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .data-container {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .data-container p {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Data Display</h1>

  <div class="data-container">
    <h2>Received Data:</h2>
    <p id="temperature-d"></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
    ipcRenderer.on("temperature-d", (event, temperature) => {
    const receivedDataElement = document.getElementById("temperature-d");
    receivedDataElement.innerText = temperature;
  });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

For now, I am just trying to display temperature data , but it is not getting displayed on GUI

Comment: Can you please add your `preload.js` script to your question.